# Leaflet Coordinate Control in R

Tags: r, leaflet, coordinates, rstudio

I'm working with Leaflet in RStudio. Now, I would like to capture the mouseclick and get its coordinates on a map. Something like [this](https://github.com/zimmicz/Leaflet-Coordinates-Control).

Do you know how to adapt that code for leaflet in R?

Comment: if hover is enough, try `mapview::addMouseCoordinates()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already tried addMouseCoordinates(). But I would like to copy and paste the coordinates. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do it with addMouseCoordinates().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the Shiny library you can use input$map_click, where map is the name of your map.:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
  leafletMap(
    "map", "100%", 400,
    initialTileLayer = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    initialTileLayerAttribution = HTML('Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>'),
    options=list(
      center = c(37.45, -93.85),
      zoom = 4,
      maxBounds = list(list(17, -180), list(59, 180))))),

 server = function(input, output, session){
    map = createLeafletMap(session, 'map')

    observe({
      click<-input$map_click
      if(is.null(click))
    return()
      text<-paste("Lattitude ", click$lat, "Longtitude ", click$lng)
        map$showPopup( click$lat, click$lng, text)
     })
  }
)
```